# How to perform aligned Interlocked.CompareExchange of Int64 in x86

Tags: c#, x86, memory-alignment, interlocked

I almost went crazy when trying to debug a random 40x performance drop when running in x86 on an algorithm which make heavy use of Interlock.CompareExchange with an Int64.

I finally isolated the issue and it occurred only when the said Int64 was not 8-bytes aligned.

No matter how I explicitly position the field in a StructLayout, its dependent on the base address of the outer object on the heap. On x86 the base address will be either 4-bytes aligned or 8-bytes aligned.

I thought of defining a 12 bytes struct and set the Int64 at offset 0 or offset 4 depending on the alignment, but that's kinda hacky.

Is there a good practice in c# for performing Interlocked operation on Int64 in x86 that guarantees the proper alignment?

---

EDIT

The code can be found here:
https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/pull/1569#discussion-diff-47997213R520

Its a threadpool implementation based on the Clr ThreadPool. The issue is about storing the state of a custom semaphore in a 8 bytes struct and modifying it with InterlockedCompareExchange64.

Comment: Does it get aligned if you put the `long` field after a `double`? Though that's a bit more size overhead obviously

Comment: You'll have to allocate memory from the Large Object Heap to get an 8-byte alignment guarantee.  That takes an allocation of at least 80,000 bytes.  Marshal.AllocHGlobal() and Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem() also ensure 8-byte alignment.  How these allocations could be practical in your case is very hard to guess.  Do note how your "kinda hacky" approach cannot work, the alignment changes when the garbage collector compacts the heap; you don't know when that happens.  By far the simplest way to do this is to just remove the jitter forcing so your app runs in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @HansPassant Good point about the GC compaction, however it could still work if the instance is pinned. Your options are interesing but LOH is not an option; I'd prefer stay in managed memory and not use AllocHGlobal; and unfortunatly this is a library that could be used in x86 processes.

Comment: You cannot pin a struct.  If you want help then you'll have to post code that somebody can give practical advice about.

Comment: I meant pin the class containing the struct. I'll update the question with the code.

Comment: @HansPassant I updated the question with the actual code, thanks.